# phonegap IOS application size

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova

I created phonegap app for both android and IOS using eclips and xcode4.5

The size of Andorid app is 650KB

The size of IOS app is 9MB!!!

I created empty phonegap app (just did create on terminal) and got the same size

How can I reduce the IOS application size ?

Thanks!

Comment: max size for iOS app submission is 2 GB my dear - have no fear...!!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The standard iOS App includes lots of Artwork, e.g. for the CDVCapture plugin.
If you don't use the Capture API (which is likely), you could save 2.3MB by deleting the `Capture.bundle` in the Resources folder and removing `CDVCapture` from the Plugins list in the `Cordova.plist`.

[image: Capture.bundle]
[image: rm CDVCapture from plugins]

Of course much of the filesize is caused by the various splash screens, icons and maybe artwork you use yourself. There is a very good way to minimize the cost of these. Get [ImageOptim](http://imageoptim.com/) and drop your Xcode project folder on it. This will reduce the filesize of your images dramatically (without losing quality). One last step: Xcode recompresses all of the artwork, so they have a bigger filesize again (stupid, right?). Go to the `Build Settings` tab and type `PNG` into the search field. Set `Compress PNG files` to `NO`.
[image: Compress PNG files]

[further reading on imageoptim & Xcode](http://imageoptim.com/xcode.html)

The whole process should reduce your App by at least 50%, please report back how much you could achieve, thanks.

Comment: @SharonMantin Do you have an universal App, or just an iPad or iPhone version? Because if you don't want to support let's say the iPad you could completly delete its artwork. Report back so I can edit/expand my answer.

Comment: I am using xcode 6 and swift and facing a similar issue, do you have any additional tips for that?

Answer (score 1):

That would be the retina splash screen images.

10MB is a normal app size, don't worry about it.

Comment: all splash screens together are less then 1MB