# What size can my iOS apps be with PhoneGap (Build vs. xCode)?

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova, size

I'm trying to find out the specifics about app size limits for PhoneGap Apps. There seems to be a lot of conflicting information and I was looking for something up to date.

I've looked at this question: [phonegap IOS application size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13697409/phonegap-ios-application-size) and between it and a few other sites that I've seen it looks like I can use PhoneGap Build for apps up to 10-15MB, or a native app through xCode up to 2GB, but I've been unable to ascertain whether there is a size limit for PhoneGap Apps built through xCode using the PhoneGap/Cordova libraries.

I'm looking into options for the distribution of an app and need to decide whether the app is distributed with links to streaming videos (Vimeo) - app size ~40MB or whether to include the videos as part of the distributed application - app size ~600MB.

Thanks for your time and help.

Cheers,

-Ryan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PhoneGap apps that you build locally via Xcode have exactly the sae size constraints as native apps. The current limit is 2GBytes - see the following:

[Max size of an iOS application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4753100/max-size-of-an-ios-application)

The only reason PhoneGap Build imposes its own limits is because it is a web / cloud based service.

Comment: Thanks, that was my thought but was just looking at confirmation before moving ahead. Thanks for your help.